# how to give authentication pf any page ? give the code to solve this question

Tags: asp.net

i want that only sign in user can only see the page .other user cannot see befor sign in?

Answer (score 1):

There's a walkthrough at the below link that shows how to set up the built in authentication model for ASP.net:

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020220.htm